# PySimpleGUI constantly displaying the file explorer

Tags: pysimplegui

As we all know, `PySimpleGUI.FileBrowse()` or `PySimpleGUI.FolderBrowse()` will open a "file explorer" such that the user can select a file or foler. Is it possible, in PySimpleGUI, to actually make a file explorer? That is, can I make the file explorer constantly displayed say on the left side of my interface such that left click on any file counts as an event, just like the case in windows ?

Comment: You can refer https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Tree_Element.py
https://github.com/jason990420/PySimpleGUI-Solution/issues/97

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.